mixture regression models with concomitants
I would like to know if the concomitant variables in mixture regression models need to be uncorrelated and, in case, why and how to handle possible correlation between them.
I am asking a theoretical question and I expect an explanation. Thanks to who will answer!

First let's make sure we both mean the same thing by "concomitant variable".
Using the definition from this vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/mixture-regressions.pdf

A general model class of finite mixtures of regression models is
considered in the following. The mixture is assumed to consist of K
components where each component follows a parametric distribution.
Each component has a weight assigned which indicates the a-priori
probability for an observation to come from this component and the
mixture distribution is given by the weighted sum over the K
components. If the weights depend on further variables, these are
referred to as concomitant variables.

With that out of the way, note that the vignette refers to several different formulations that may treat concomitant variables slightly differently. But in flexmix, there is no requirement that concomitant variables are uncorrelated. See page 4 of the vignette: "The mapping function only has to fulfill condition (1)." - which is condition that the sum of weights for any observations must sum to 1.
The concomitant model is not really that special in that it makes a prediction of something given some explanatory data. The prediction is the class probabilities and the explanatory data are the concomitant variables. Those variables can have any arbitrary joint distribution. The only requirement is that you are able to use them to form a prediction of probabilities which sum to 1.
